# Is it a chain of promises i need

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise, q

I have a function which I need to run after several Ajax calls are complete. Each AJAX call is  currently called one after another and currently do work within their respective callbacks. Is this a candidate for a promise chain as each ajax call only runs if its respective test is true? And I don't necessarily need these calls to be serially run just that I get one callback at the end  (when all the Ajax calls which fulfilled the criteria to be run completed their respective callbacks).

```
if(MyTest1){
  RunMyAjaxCall1(param1,param2,successAjaxCallback1,failureAjaxCallback1);
}
if(MyTest2){
  RunMyAjaxCall2(param1,param2,successAjaxCallback2,failureAjaxCallback2);
}
if(MyTest3){
  RunMyAjaxCall3(param1,param2,successAjaxCallback3,failureAjaxCallback3);
}
if(MyTest4){
  RunMyAjaxCall4(param1,param2,successAjaxCallback4,failureAjaxCallback4);
}
```

Sample AJAX Call

```
RunMyAjaxCall1 = function (param1,param2, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        datatype: 'json',
        url: "/WebServices/GlobalWebService.asmx/webservicemethod1",
        data: JSON.stringify({ param1: param1, param2: param2 }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (data) { successCallback(data.d); },
        error: function (data) { failureCallback(data.d) }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this:

```
var requests = [];
if (MyTest1) {
    requests.push(RunMyAjaxCall1(param1,param2,successAjaxCallback1,failureAjaxCallback1));
}
// ...continue with other if statements

$.when.apply(null, requests).always(function () {
    // All handlers used are done (either succeeded or failed)
});
```

Since you said you were making AJAX calls, I assume you're using `$.ajax`. The value returned from calling `$.ajax` is a `Promise`. The `RunMyAjaxCallX` functions need to return this in order for this scheme to work.

Using `requests` allows for a dynamic way to group requests. The `if` statements determine which are executed and included.

The use of `$.when` (with passing `requests` as an argument) creates a new `Promise`, encompassing all requests that you determined should be included. Then using the `.always()` method, it will run when all included requests are completed.

**Here's an example of it working:** http://jsfiddle.net/vmw8H/

Some reference:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/

Comment: Couldn't really tell by glancing at the Documentation, does this approach ensure that Call1 fires and completes before Call2 and so on and so forth (essentially make the calls synchronous)? Or does it for loop through and just attempt to invoke all of the calls asynchronously and wait for all to return with an status of successful?

Comment: @FeistyMango I think I understand what you're asking, and the answer is yes (to your first question). Inside the `if` statements, the `$.ajax` calls should be initiated (and `return`ed). Then, using `$.when`, it groups them into one big `Promise`. When all of the included `$.ajax` calls complete (whether they're `resolve`d or `reject`ed), the `.always()` method is executed.

Comment: @FeistyMango Since jQuery `Promise`s have special structure, there's no looping necessary. Internally, when the AJAX request comes back, that specific `Promise` is either `.resolve()`d or `.reject()`ed. `$.when` will wait for all included before executing `.always()`

Comment: added a sample ajax call to clarify.  You say a .ajax call returns a promise, My global callback needs to run after each ajax call's callback method has completed rather than after each ajax call has completed.

Comment: @Ian The .always() and .then() functions make perfect sense. My concern is the the OP listed a requirement where each call must behave synchronously i.e until you get the returned status of Call 1, Call 2 can not be invoked, and likewise, until Call 2's status is received, you cannot invoked Call 3 and so on. This code seems to just invoke all the Calls at once and wait for the return status of each of them

Comment: @Ian Ahhhh, I missed that. I was focusing on `Each AJAX call is currently called one after another` You get my upvote =P

Comment: @FeistyMango Originally, they said "And I don't necessarily need these calls to be serially run just that I get one callback at the end" (sorry, deleted the original comment on accident)

Comment: @FeistyMango No problem, I keep re-reading and I'm a little confused *exactly* what's wanted now

Comment: i said they dont need to be called synchronously, I do need to know when the callback methods of each ajax call has completed. the example being each ajax call is retrieving data from an external source, which needs processing and adding to the DOM. when all valid callbacks have completed this i need to get a callback. HTHs

Comment: @Tim I'm confused...at first you said "just that I get one callback at the end (when all the Ajax calls which fulfilled the criteria to be run completed their respective callbacks)."

Comment: @ian sorry for confusion, i just want a single callback to at the end of all processing to run .i.e 4 ajax calls with their 4 ajax callbacks. after everything has completed there  should be 1 final callback not one per ajax call. Hope this clarifies

Comment: @Tim That's what I thought you meant. But then it seemed like you changed it in your last few comments. I'm pretty sure that's exactly the point of my code, and is what it does.

Comment: @Ian just tried this sample code with some console.logs and i can see that the global callback gets fired after each of the ajax calls complete, but not after their subsequent successcallbacks complete, they also start executing as soon as they are pushed into the array, which i wasnt expecting i thought the apply method would execute the calls

Comment: Guys, whole discussion - need to replace "synchronously" with "sequentially" all through.

Comment: @Tim I updated my answer with a jsFiddle example that attempts to mimic your code. Notice how 3 calls are made (and successfully completed), **then** the `.always()` callback fires **once**. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: @Ian thanks mate, yes i got it to work, just been on holiday so late to respond

Comment: @Tim No problem, I just wanted to make sure you weren't still struggling with it :)